# Using Python to Scrape Interview Questions from Student Doctor Network (SDN)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am a python novice, and I'm developing a to scrape medical school interview questions from Student Doctor Network, a popular forum for pre-medical students. I am unsure of what is the simplest way to create a program that randomly prints an interview question from any specific school.

Sample Page with questions: https://www.studentdoctor.net/schools/school/emory/survey/26/emory-university-school-of-medicine/1

I am unsure if BeautifulSoup is the right path to take, but would appreciate any help or guidance in finding the best way to pull interview questions for my program. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example how to extract the questions from the page:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.studentdoctor.net/schools/school/emory/survey/26/emory-university-school-of-medicine/1"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
for question in soup.select("h3"):
    q = question.get_text(strip=True).replace("\n", " ")
    if q.endswith("?"):
        print(q)
```

Prints:

```
How to tell strength of clinical years?
How did the interview impress you?
What was the stress level of the interview?
How you think you did?
How do you rank this school among ALL other schools?
How long was the interview?
Where did the interview take place?
What was the style of the interview?
What type of interview was it?
How many people interviewed you?
What is one of the specific questions they asked you (question 1)?
What is one of the specific questions they asked you (question 2)?
What is one of the specific questions they asked you (question 3)?
What was the most interesting question?
What was the most difficult question?
How did you prepare for the interview?
What impressed you positively?
What impressed you negatively?
What did you wish you had known ahead of time?
What are your general comments?
Who was the tour given by?
How did the tourguide seem?
How do you rank the facilities?
What is your in-state status?
What was your total time spent traveling?
What was your primary mode of travel?
About how much did you spend on room, food, and travel?
What airport did you use?
Where did you stay?
What is the name of the hotel you stayed in?
Would you recommend the hotel?
How do you rank this school among other schools to which you've applied?
What is your ranking of this school's location?
What is your ranking of this area's cultural life?
How is the responsiveness of the admissions office?
How is the friendliness of the admissions office?
How eco-friendly are the school's application materials and interview process?
What are your suggestions for the admissions office?
```